How to create `/run` folder and possibly subfolders?
For the past few years, running xdf yields the warning
$QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-fma'
QXcbShmImage: shmget() failed (88: Function not implemented) for size 3208656 (1133x708)

According to this page.  I need the following in my ~/.bashrc:
export XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/$(id -u)

I using Cygwin, and I don't have a folder /run.  I want to create it, but I'm not sure how best to do so in a way that all accounts can use it.  I have an admin account and various other accounts for different purposes, e.g.,. personal, work-related, gaming, etc.
How should I create /run?  Should I also create /run/user for different accounts?

I really doubt you want to do this. /run isn't a normal directory, it is usually a tmpfs filesystem created at boot. If cygwin doesn't already have one, creating that directory and tricking programs to believe that you have a real /run when you don't is almost certainly a very bad idea. If this isn't causing you any problems, just alias xdf to xdf 2>/dev/null so you don't see the error and be done with it.

I guess I can just ignore the warning message.  Did you want to post your comment as an answer?  I didn't realize that /run wasn't a normal directory.

See the Filesystem Hierarcy Standard at https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/fhs.shtml, or read man hier. It explains where things go.
About /run it says:

3.15. /run : Run-time variable data
3.15.1. Purpose
This directory contains system information data
describing the system since it was booted. Files under this directory must be cleared (removed or truncated as appropriate) at the beginning of the boot process.
The purposes of this directory were once served by /var/run. In general, programs may continue to use /var/run to fulfill the requirements set out for /run for the purposes of backwards compatibility. Programs which have migrated to use /run should cease their usage of /var/run, except as noted in the section on /var/run.
Programs may have a subdirectory of /run; this is encouraged for programs that use more than one run-time file. Users may also have a subdirectory of /run, although care must be taken to appropriately limit access rights to prevent unauthorized use of /run itself and other subdirectories

So, feel free to create /run and subdirectories.
After creating /run, perhaps by mounting it as a tmpfs,
# Or, create it on the `/` filesystem
sudo mkdir --mode=0777 /run
sudo mkdir --mode=0755 /run/users

and so forth.
You could create multiple subdirectories at once, using shell expansion: sudo mkdir --parents /run/users/{me,you,them}

Thanks, this is informative.  I think I'll keep away from actually creating /run because I'd have to know the rationale for the file permissions.  If it wasn't so easy to just ignore the warning, I'd spend the time to research this, but for now, it's a matter of competing priorities.
